# Avoid TAB on a Div in browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have JQuery slide in-out div, which slides in-out on click of a button

**The Problem#**
when i open it in broswer, and start pressing TAB, when the selection reaches the options of that div(which slides), the slide div comes out(become visible without clicking on button).

is there any way by which that slide div can avoid TAB selection..

CHECK HERE http://global.redhatsalesteam.com/slide_test/

Comment: Can we see your code? You can also try hiding off-screen elements so they don't get focus.

Comment: Check it here http://global.redhatsalesteam.com/slide_test/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the tabindex on your links to -1.  that should take them out of the tab order.   if you want them to be tab-able to when you open the menu, you can set them back to something reasonable in the complete call back.

something like this should do it:

```
$('#slidemarginleft .button').click(function() {
  $marginLefty.animate({
    marginLefty: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ?
    $marginLefty.outerWidth() : 0
  },
  function(){
     var counter = 1;
     if($marginLeft.is(':visible'){ 
         $marginLefty.find('a').each(function(){
             $(this).attr('tabindex', counter);
             counter++;
         });
     }
     else{
          $marginLefty.find('a').attr('tabindex', '-1');
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Start off with the display of the animated div at `display: none;` - this will mean the links inside it can't get focus from "tabbing" - then on click (in the function) change it to `display: block` just before starting the slide animation

```
var $marginLefty = $('#slidemarginleft div.inner');
$marginLefty.css({
  marginLeft: $marginLefty.outerWidth() + 'px',
  display: 'none'
});

$('#slidemarginleft .button').click(function() {
  $marginLefty.css('display', 'block').animate({
    marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ?
    $marginLefty.outerWidth() : 0
  });
});
```